# onFling method of Gallery not getting called on swipe of images

Tags: android

I have MYGallery class extended by Gallery. onSwipe onFling method is not getting called what need to do.

code is as below

```
public MyGallery(PhotoAlbumDetailActivity context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
        //this.setSpacing(10);
    }

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
  System.out.println("On Fling");
  return true;
}
```

in my main activity 
        this.mConverseGallery = new ConverseGallery(this);

Comment: fo you have a GestureDetector or something ?

Answer (score 0):

`onFling()` method must return a boolean value:

```
public MyGallery(PhotoAlbumDetailActivity context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    //this.setSpacing(10);
}

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.i("test", "onFling()");
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

Comment: yes i did that sorry ..just edited my question have look still it is not getting called onFling();

Comment: do i need to set any listener for this? I dont understand it is not working here?

Comment: Actually you should not use `System.out.println` when working with Android SDK but rather [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)